# Using a button to open a url

Tags: c++, objective-c, url, object, uiwebview

So I already made an app, and I have all working funntcions, but I have made a button in the corner with this command

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com/"]]];
```

and when I click button, nothing happens.
I am trying to make the button load up a page :)
Please help, and thank you! :)

Comment: where is the webView? Is it already on the current viewcontroller?

Comment: Yeah, but i wanna make a button that will take me to a URL, i made button I just need the code so when i click button a URL is requested and opens..

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't connect the WebView with your outlet called webView.

Answer (score 0):

use this code if you want to open a website in Safari

```
NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Or use this code, if you want to open a website in a UIWebview

```
 NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
 NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
 NSLog(@"url = %@",nsurl);
 NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
 [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

Also, make sure you've connected your Outlets properly.

Comment: I tryed both, first one makes url open in safari, but second one keeps it on the same url, in other words... The 2nd code you gave me did nothing.

Comment: Here's a simple project i've made for you. just d/wld it and run.... :)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pu25rqdq9q52sfj/webTest.zip?m

Comment: @ModH4ck When you click on the button, then wait for the website to open, because it depends on your internet connection's speed how fast a site opens.... :)